# TSLint combine imports

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, jslint

I get a tslint error that those imports can be combined in a single line:

```
import { ActionTypes } from './actions';
import * as actions from './actions';
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
import * as actions, { ActionTypes } from './actions';
```

How can I combine those two imports?

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as actions from './actions'
```

accesses all from './actions'.
You can access ActionTypes from the 'actions' alias you defines in

```
import * as actions
```

So to get to ActionTypes you start with

```
actions.ActionTypes or actions.foo.bar.ActionTypes
```

if ActionTypes is embedded somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, but I still want to use the `ActionTypes` alias, without having to write `actions.ActionTypes` or manually creating an alias via copying that in a different variable.

Comment: try " import './actions' " . That should import everything.

Comment: You can disable the lint rule also. That would be the easiest way to go about it.

Comment: So it's impossible to combine both imports in a single line?

Comment: I just tried importing the file like " import './actions' " with a library in a project I have and it works. So try that and see if you can access actionTypes. But if you want to use your alias of actions and ActionTypes in the same line I do think that is impossible. Once you alias the library that's its name from then on.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading in this case. You can't combine these imports into single line. What you **can** do, is to define alias for `ActionTypes`:

```
import * as actions from './actions';
import ActionTypes = actions.ActionTypes;
```

Comment: So it's actually an issue with the TSLint error message :(